# Ambiguous reference to overloaded definition

Tags: scala

The following:

```
object SomeObj {
  def addVertex(cc: Product): String = ???
  def addVertex(cc: AnyRef): String = ???
}

case class Toto(s: String)

SomeObj.addVertex(Toto(""))
```

Is doing:

```
Error:(8, 10) ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method addVertex in object SomeObj of type (cc: Object)String
and  method addVertex in object SomeObj of type (cc: Product)String
match argument types (A$A34.this.Toto)
SomeObj.addVertex(Toto(""));}
        ^
```

Why? Shouldn't it go for the most specific one?
Interestingly with `Any` instead of `AnyRef` it works.

Cheers

Comment: Not really, your example works for me without the mentioned error. What version of Scala are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
trait Product extends Any with Equals 
trait Equals extends Any
```

Here you can see that `Product` does not extend `AnyRef` and not derived from it, so it is not more specific than `AnyRef` and compiler can't choose among them. But `Product` is a subclass of `Any`, therefore it is more specific than `Any`, that's why your another variant compiles succesfully.